# RSA in Java given n and e

Tags: java, rsa, encryption, bouncycastle

My application receives the raw pieces of a public RSA key (n and e) and needs to use these to encrypt a cipher text.  I've been trying to use BouncyCastle but my code isn't working.  The problem arises in trying to create the X509EncodedKeySpec.

Can anyone help me get this working?  Here's the code I have:

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws Exception
{
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64Encoder.decode(key));

    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    return publicKey;
}
```

I guess the real problem is that n and e are separate and I don't know how to combine them.

Comment: Why isn't your code working? Doesn't it compile? Does it throw an exception at run-time? What's the error message?

Comment: Sorry, you're right I should have specified.  It throws an InvalidKeySpecException at the generatePublic function.  My fault for not including that detail.

Comment: Basically, I need to encrypt some plaintext given n and e.

Comment: Why do you believe the key is in the correct format for an X509EncodedKeySpec? It is absolutely critical that you understand exactly how the `n` and `e` are formatted and stored in the `key` argument before any progress can be made. Also, I don't anything Bouncycastle related in your code fragment.

Comment: Consider reading this tutorial: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml (in particular page 2)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial Giacomo, that definitely was what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you not using new RSAPublicKeySpec(n,e)?

Comment: Note that it is important to use the BigInteger constructor BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude) with signum=1 if you have the values as byte array otherwise you will get sometimes negative BigInteger values with are not valid for RSA.

Comment: @Robert Yup, negative integers or wrong endianess is indeed a source for errors. But the OP does not specify the the format of n and e, so I can't tell him how convert those integers correctly.

Comment: Well, the main reason I wasn't using that was because I did not know it existed.  Worked like a charm though, thank you. :D

Answer (score -1):

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws Exception
        {
            BASE64Decoder b64 = new BASE64Decoder();
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(b64.decodeBuffer(key));
            PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
            return publicKey;
        }
```